# Adafruit BMP280 Temperature Sensor with Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, android-things, adafruit

I am using Adafruit BMP280 Temperature sensor breakout board with Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.
OS- Android things.

I am using library:  https://github.com/androidthings/drivers-samples/tree/master/bmx280

Hardware connections-

[image]

Temperature sensor is working but intermittently sensor gives -135.9237, 179.63043, -128.93599, 188.4 values continuously for sometime. 
After some period of time, it starts giving correct temperature automatically.
I do not know the reason. I have to solve this issue. 
I am new in this. 
Can anyone help me in this?

Wrong Temp: [image]

[image]

Comment: How long does it take to get to expected values?

Comment: Not fixed. Sometimes it takes 1 hour and sometimes it takes 24 hours to get to expected values.

Comment: And sometimes it takes only 15-20 minutes.

Comment: Is it potentially a defect of the part?

Comment: I have 10 numbers of sensor. And the problem is same with all these sensors.
I don't think, there is any defect of the part.

Comment: Please can you check your wiring? - you appear to have connections for both I2C operation SD1->GPI02/SCK->GPI03 and for SPI operation however for SPI you have the SD0 data pin tied to +5V rail on the Pi which doesn't seem right. For I2C operation Adafruit say to leave the other data pins disconnected. So my instinct is to use one connection method at a time. Also please check: you're putting 5V on Vin for the sensor board which I think is making your output logic levels from the sensor 5V however the RPi logic levels are 3v3 from memory, I could be wrong but it could cause problems too.

Comment: @Hargrovm
Sir!

As per datasheet of BMP280, it says "Connecting SDO to GND results in slave address 1110110(0x76); connection it to VDDIO results in slave address 1110111(0x77), which is the same as BMP180’s I²C address. The SDO pin cannot be left floating; if left floating, the I²C address will be undefined"
The library which I have used there is I2C address is 0x77. So, I connected SD0 to 5V.

For 5V on Vin, I will check this and connect it to 3.3V and then I will monitor the sensor.

Comment: Are you using a BMP280 sensor mounted on a breakout board as shown in your link for the library you are using or are you using the bare device in your own circuit? Because that would be important to know. The schematic in the link you provided shows a BMP280 breakout board attached to a Pi with Vin attached to the 5V Pi rail (so I2C isn't as sensitive to the voltage level shift as I thought or perhaps its handled on the board??)  but they don't show a connection to SD0. If you are using the device in your own circuit then please provide a schematic.

Comment: @Hargrovm
I am using breakout board.

Comment: Then if you leave SD0 disconnected on the board it is not left floating on the device because the board includes a pull-up circuit to 3v3 as you can see from the Adafruit board schematic. You are trying to pull SD0 up to 5v and probably succeeding. I'm guessing the datasheet, you are reading, that references VDDIO is the component datasheet which also warns against applying voltage to logic pins before VDD  and VDDIO, because it damages the device. This could be happening because the on board regulator causes a delay. 5V on SD0 isn't healthy check the Adafruit BMP280 tutorial.

Comment: @Hargrovm
Okay. I will leave SD0 float and then monitor this.
Can this be the only reason for negative temperature reading values?

Comment: I don't know - I've not used this board or the device but from experience if hardware is misbehaving then one of the first places to look is wiring and loose connections, then consider that I might have fried the device or its faulty, failing that: my software is wrong - if you are just using the test sample then I doubt that it's the software. Try a fresh board with only the connections shown in the links and tutorial and see how far you get.

Comment: @Hargrovm
Okay.
I will test this and will post the result here.

Comment: @Hargrovm
Hi 
I have tested it with the connection 5V,Gnd,SCK,SD1 but sensor stops working after sometime so I had checked voltage on SD0 which selects communication, there was GND on SD0, it meant SPI but I am working on I2C.
I have connected SD0 to 5V also and sensor starts working and did not stop. I made connection with small jumper wire for 4 days and read expected values.
So, I decided to install it in the fridge with long wire connection so I installed it in the fridge. But after some hours sensor gave -135 value two times in 24 hours.

I do not why.

Comment: @Hargrovm

Now it is giving unexpected value at any time
I have attached the photo of wrong temp value also.

Comment: So going back to your original wiring SD0 -> +5v gives the same results as before??  If you are putting electronics in a domestic fridge its going to be damp inside and condensation will likely occur. Electronics and moisture invariably don't mix. Check your wiring and connections for dry joints? The information you provide is limited, I can fill some gaps with datasheets but there is no wiring diagram / photo, no component list or code and as I've said I have no special knowledge of the board.Its an Adafruit board and tutorial why not post on their forum https://forums.adafruit.com/ ?

Comment: @Hargrovm
Can you please let me know if you have any idea that how much length of wire can be connected with the BMP280 Breakout board?
Because I think it can be the length of wire issue

Comment: The answer to your question is it depends: on the wire you are using and the expected data rate. There's a discussion on this electronics.stackexchange question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106265/maximum-i2c-bus-length on the same subject. As you can see - the answer there is: it depends but roughly they suggest no more than a couple of meters for any kind of performance.

Comment: Okay. 
I will check this because I have concluded that when I use .15 m cable, receive expected values , I have monitored this for 4 days.
And when I use 1.5 m cable then receive unexpected values at anytime within 1 day.

Comment: @Hargrovm Hi SIr! I have checked the BMP280 breakout module with the library
https://github.com/androidthings/driver ... ter/bmx280
And I received these values when I unplugged and plugged the sensor from the running Raspberry Pi. Now I am confused what can be the issue.
2020-04-23 23:59:53.785 1686-1686/com.example.androidthings.driversamples I/TemperatureActivity: sensor changed: 28.17394
2020-04-23 23:59:59.023 1686-1686/com.example.androidthings.driversamples I/TemperatureActivity: sensor changed: 181.25519
sensor changed: 180.64856